# Spring json map elements with different names to list

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I use spring boot 2.1.4 and my problem is with json map to object. Is it possible to map json like this

```
{
   "name":"test",
   "list1":1,
   "list2":2,
   "list3":3,
   "list4":4,
   "list5":5,
   "list6":6,
   "list7":7
}
```

to object like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Test {

    private String name;
    private List<Integer> list;

}
```

in my spring boot controller it's look like this:

```
@GetMapping("/criteria")
public String registration(@RequestBody Test test) {
    return "";
}
```

Is it some way to map this json to my custom object?

Comment: I think you need custom (de)serializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@JsonAnySetter** If you wanna use `Map` instead if `List` you can consider `@JsonAnySetter` and in the program where ever you need just do `properties.values()`

Allows us the flexibility of using a Map as standard properties. On deserialization, the properties from JSON will simply be added to the map.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Test {

    private String name;
    private Map<String, String> properties;

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void add(String key, String value) {
       properties.put(key, value);
     }

}
```

You can also try with `List` using `@JsonAnySetter`

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Test {

    private String name;
    private List<Integer> properties;

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void add(String key, Integer value) {
       properties.add(value);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a custom deserializer for the object see below.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer::class)
data class MyCustomObject(
    var name: String,
    var list: List<Int>
)

class CustomDeserializer: JsonDeserializer<MyCustomObject>(){
    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): MyCustomObject {
        var myList = ArrayList<Int>()
        var myName = ""
        while(p.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT){
            if(p.currentName() == "name"){
                myName = p.nextTextValue()
            }
            if(p.currentName().contains("list")){
                myList.add(p.nextIntValue(0))
            }
        }

        return MyCustomObject(myName, myList)
    }
}
```

This was written in Kotlin, if you need my help converting it to java let me know.

***EDIT*** Went ahead and converted it to Java for you. Please excuse any typos :) let me know if you have any questions or issues

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
public class MyCustomObjectAgain {
    private String name;
    private List<Integer> myList;

    public MyCustomObjectAgain(String name, List<Integer> myList) {
        this.name = name;
        this.myList = myList;
    }

    private class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyCustomObject>{
        @Override
        public MyCustomObject deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList();
            String myName = "";
            while(p.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT){
                if(p.currentName() == "name"){
                    myName = p.nextTextValue();
                }
                if(p.currentName().contains("list")){
                    myList.add(p.nextIntValue(0));
                }
            }

            return new MyCustomObject(myName, myList);
        }
    }
}
```